# c# http post get data from Request.Form in readable string format

Tags: c#, http, post, format

i have this on client side

```
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "/FileManager/SavePivotFile",
                data: JSON.stringify(tempOptions),
                params: {
                    fileName: $stateParams.report.FileName
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
            })
            .then(function (success) {
                showNotification('The changes have been saved.', 'info');
            }, function (error) {
                showNotification('Failed to save the file.', 'error');
            });
```

And this on server

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public void SavePivotFile(string fileName)
    {
        var qqq = Request.Form;

    }
```

When i send the data in server i get the string like `"{%7b%22dataSource%22%3a%7b%22type%22%3a%22xmla%22%2c%22c"`

How can format this to human readable format like: `"{"dataSource":{"type":"xmla","columns":[{"name"`

So later can write this to a file?

Comment: Why do you specify "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" header and use JSON.stringify at the same time?

Comment: @mtkachenko Json.Stringfy is just to  put an object  in plain  string

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel I know, but it's not form. I'm just thinking about more elegant approach. In this case - yes, you use "x-www-form-urlencoded" so you need to make urldecode on server.

Comment: @mtkachenko Just put the elegant way in  the commentbecause it's beyond the scope of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can just use UrlDecode

```
var str=   HttpUtility.UrlDecode("%7b%22dataSource%22%3a%7b%22type%22%3a%22xmla%22%2c%22c");
```

But I think that your Json Doc  is not complete

**Note**
You have to reference `System.Web` if It is not done

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid encode/decode. On client side:

```
var somedata = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Send", "Test")',
            data: { Content: JSON.stringify(somedata) }
        });
```

On server:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Send(Data data)
    {
        return data.Content;
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

In this case you will get normal json in *data.Content* property.